# How can I play my own courses without uploading them?

Tags: super-mario-maker

Whenever I save a course, it goes into the "World" levels, but I can't find that world window other than when saving.

How can I play my own levels without uploading each of them and is it possible to play the world levels in order?

Comment: I'm not familiar with mario maker but it would appear after looking [here](http://supermariomaker.nintendo.com/manual/page_04.html#open02) that the coursebot should have a play option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can play your own courses by going to the coursebot menu and choosing play.
More details on menu options [here](http://supermariomaker.nintendo.com/manual/page_04.html#touch)

Answer (score 1):

On the Super Mario Maker menu click "Make." Then click a yellow icon on the top right corner with some white bars. Then click an icon with a robot called "Coarsebot." There, you can see the levels you've made and you can play them, edit them, and upload them. You can play them without having to upload them.